# MySQL 1h record of the past 24h

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I use:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

To fetch all records in the last 24h. Is there a way to "filter" from MySQL to fetch only one value of each hour in that 24h period? I dont really mind if its the 1st record or the last record of every hour.

date is in Mysql timestamp and is used as the primary key (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

Why? i insert a temperature record every minute and then i draw it using Google Chart. When i draw the chart of the past 24h it looks crazy!! Since its a home DIY project im fine with drawing the temperature chart in the last 24h with 1h interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY group by hour(date)
```

Comment: At 1st glance its working perfectly. Outputs the last record of each hour for the past 24h. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data by the hour and select for instance the lowest `id` for every hour. If you join that subquery against your table - you will get the desired result

```
select d1.*
from data d1
join
(
  SELECT min(id) as id
  FROM data 
  group by date(date), hour(date)
) d2 on d1.id = d2.id
WHERE d1.date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: It should be `date` and `hour` to be precise

Comment: Please explain your answer. Thanks!

Comment: not working for me ... I dont have d1 or d2 colums defined .... I just have a column named date (type timestamp, used as primary key and automatically filled with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

Comment: `d1` and `d2` are just table name aliases. for the `data` table and the subquery.